# LLVM: commnad not found llvm-readobj

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

While trying to build sample qt app for android, stuck with below errors.

> Command does not exist:
>   /Users/sungyong/Library/Android/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/llvm-readobj
>   Command does not exist:
>   /Users/sungyong/Library/Android/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/llvm-readobj
>   Command does not exist:
>   /Users/sungyong/Library/Android/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/llvm-readobj
>   Command does not exist:
>   /Users/sungyong/Library/Android/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/llvm-readobj
>   Command does not exist:
>   /Users/sungyong/Library/Android/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/llvm-readobj
>   Command does not exist:
>   /Users/sungyong/Library/Android/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/llvm-readobj
>   Command does not exist:
>   /Users/sungyong/Library/Android/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/llvm-strip
>   11:26:20: The process
>   "/Users/sungyong/Qt/5.12.2/android_arm64_v8a/bin/androiddeployqt"
>   exited with code 9. Error while building/deploying project qtempty
>   (kit: Android for arm64-v8a (Clang Qt 5.12.2 for Android ARM64-v8a))
>   When executing step "Build Android APK"

Even though googling correct solution, still have no idea.

What do I check?
There's is no 'llvm-readobj' at this path even though I follow guide.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you need to update your NDK. It's there in a current release.

Answer (score 2):

I've also encountered a similar problem.
The error message was `llvm-strip:not found`, despite having `clang-10` on my Ubuntu system.
But I found `llvm-strip-10` in directory `/usr/bin`, it's not `llvm-strip`.
So I made soft link `llvm-strip --> llvm-strip-10` and it works.